# Can coefficients in matrix exponentials be anything?

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra, taylor-expansion

Let $A$ be a matrix with elements in some field $\mathbb{k}$. Given the matrix exponential
$$
e^{A\phi}
$$
we can use Taylor series, to write
$$
e^{A\phi} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\phi^{k}}{k!}A^k = I + \phi A + \frac{(\phi A)^2}{2!} + \frac{(\phi A)^3}{3!} + \cdots 
$$
My question is wether $\phi$ can be allowed to be an element of an arbitrary field different to $\mathbb{k}$ or even element of some other arbitrary algebraic structure (assuming that it makes sense to take powers of it).

Comment: What is $t$? Do you mean $\phi$?

Comment: I've only encountered exponential of a matrix with complex coefficients.

Comment: @angryavian yes, fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this example is more "exotic" than what you're looking for, but in the field $\mathbb{Q}_p$ of p-adic numbers, the series in question $$e^{X\phi}=I+\phi X + \frac{(\phi X)^2}{2!} + \frac{(\phi X)^3}{3!}+\cdots$$ may have *convergence issues*, even for matrices $X$ as "agreeable" as the identity matrix $X=I$. For instance, the above series does not converge in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ when $X=I$ and $\phi=1$. This is because the p-adic norm doesn't behave the same way as the usual Euclidean norm on $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Thanks. As I mentioned above, I wonder if I can consider $\phi$ as a formal variable (with nice field like properties, or at least R-module like properties) for formal manipulation of the matrix exponential. This is what I wonder. I cannot find some reference.

Answer (score 0):

If with $t$ you mean $\phi$, then no. Scalar multiplication of a matrix is still defined for elements of the field $k$. In addition, $k$ has to admit some way to define "arbitrarily large natural numbers" (those factorials have to come from somewhere), so it should have characteristic zero and an ordering for those "natural numbers" (since how else do you count up from zero to infinity?)

Comment: I fixed it, I meat $\phi$. Why can I not just allow $\phi$ to be a formal variable that does indeed admit powers. Or a ring, or some R-module?

Comment: An ordering is too strong: the series makes sense over $\mathbb{C}$, for example

Comment: @JacobManaker, I added a clarification, the ordering is only necessary for the subset which would correspond to the natural numbers.

Comment: @Marion, if you want to use rings or modules, that's fine, but then your matrix ought to be defined with regards to that particular ring and not some arbitrary field. I only went off of what you wrote and you explicitly stated that the matrix was defined over a field $k$.

Comment: Furthermore, you actually also need a topology in order to define what an infinite sum means. You could of course view that expression as a sequence of matrices where you don't need a topology (assuming that is what you mean with formal variable) however then the elements still have to be compatible with multiplicative inverses of integers which doesn't leave you much of a choice what your ring could be.

Comment: @ManateePink well, for example, I could have $A$ as real matrices and consider $\phi$ as maps $\mathbb{C}^{n\times n} \to \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ such that the image is a ring for example. I can add elements of the image, multiply, take inverses etc.

Comment: @Marion, I think I see. But then you should really clarify your post because you are saying there are 3 different kind of "multiplications" happening in each term. One only omits these kind of details in the notation if it is clear from the context however you have not provided such a thing.

Comment: Hi, sorry if it was not clear. But, would you agree or comment something on the premise?

Comment: @Marion, I probably would if you would properly edit your question. As it stands, it is too open-ended and can mean too many things, not to mention that you haven't addressed any concerns of convergence that have been raised